# Can you put an Adverb before an Adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I want to know that can we place an adverb before and adjective means what is the order of placing adjectives adverbs when used together or individually

Comment: Place an adverb before what? Please review your question. It doesn't make much sense as written.

Answer (score 1):

Adverbs that modify an adjective are called *adverbs of degree* or *intensifiers* and in most cases they go before adjectives when they are used together:

> Adverbs of degree tell us about the intensity of something. Adverbs of degree are usually placed before the adjective, adverb, or verb that they modify, although there are some exceptions. The words "too", "enough", "very", and "extremely" are examples of adverbs of degree.
>
> - The water was ***extremely** cold*.
>   ***Enough*** as an adverb meaning 'to the necessary degree' goes after the adjective or adverb that it is modifying, and not before it as other adverbs do. It can be used both in positive and negative sentences.
> - Is your coffee *hot **enough***? ([English resources](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-degree/))

Other exceptions are listed on that site.

As for word order with adverbs and adjectives used apart, it is too wide a question. you might want to narrow it down to one particular query you have. But this is a good start of research: [Adverbs and adverb phrases: position](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)

Answer (score 0):

We can put adverbs and adverb phrases at the front, in the middle or at the end of a clause.

The front position of the clause is the first item in the clause:

> - Suddenly I felt afraid.
> - Yesterday detectives arrested a man and a woman in connection with the
>     murder.

The end position of the clause is the last item in the clause:

> - Why do you always have to eat so fast?

The mid position is between the subject and the main verb:

> - Apples always taste best when you pick them straight off the tree.

Comment: means we can place it before any adjective and it will always precede adjective

Comment: An adjective usually goes next to the noun it describes. An adverb relates to the verb in the sentence. There isn't any fixed rule about which comes first.

Comment: @KateBunting adverbs do not always relate to verbs.  Sometimes an adverb relates to an adjective, as in the sentence _we enjoyed a thoroughly delightful evening._

Answer (score 0):

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/) has an interesting piece on this subject

> Place adverbs as close as possible to the words they are supposed to
> modify. Putting the adverb in the wrong spot can produce an awkward
> sentence at best and completely change the meaning at worst. Be
> especially careful about the word only, which is one of the most often
> misplaced modifiers. Consider the difference between these two
> sentences:
>
> Phillip only fed the cat. Phillip fed only the cat.
>
> The first sentence means that all Phillip did was feed the cat. He
> didn’t pet the cat or pick it up or anything else. The second sentence
> means that Phillip fed the cat, but he didn’t feed the dog, the bird,
> or anyone else who might have been around.
>
> When an adverb is modifying a verb phrase, the most natural place for
> the adverb is usually the middle of the phrase.
>
> We are quickly approaching the deadline. Phillip has always loved
> singing.
>
> I will happily assist you.

As can be seen in the above examples, it you can indeed put an adverb before an adjective.